# TypeError: Property 'postData' undefined in Web App doPost request

Tags: google-apps-script, postdata

Why does `e.postData` always show as undefined?

I try the other people's sample code, they also use `e.postData`, but their code works yet mine does not.

Here's a sample of my code:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'TfGgj205llEo+fUWZYwvv0S389cvZJrdH+vhG1lIJPWsgVc/yeZSFry8FGBYE4OfvIQpW080FGL6efM545aq7tfEZMNffOIJZBFl0pFglvqb+ioZRf1up7RZxYHQx9pHhSL7z4saMX/LM1Yw8PfWYAdB04t819/1O/w1cDnyilFU=';
  var msg= JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  console.log(msg);
}
```

Comment: Show the code of the request you are sending